# Can't stop timer repeats inside Actionlistener in Java

Tags: java, swing, timer, awt, actionlistener

I hava a simple countdown that checks every few Milliseconds if a variable is false.
When it is false, the timer should be stopped. But it does not work for me. Why? And how would I fix this? I tried multiple ways I found in other threads, but none seem to work.

```
  > final Timer countdown = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            if (Fight.isStatus()== false) {
            ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
            ((Timer)evt.getSource()).setRepeats(false);
            }
        }
    });
    
    countdown.setRepeats(true);
    countdown.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `TimerTask` instance with your task. `TimerTask task = new YourTask();` And say `task.cancel();`
I do not know how to use cancel method in your code.